# rails cancan could not find record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I use cancan to authorization, I have a model named program, and an entity featured_card which is in relation (has_many) with program entity, I use an action in my programs controller named  add_card to add a featured card to the program, my call looks like this:

```
Started POST "/admin/programs/18/add_card?card_class=Startup&program=9" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-11 05:49:59 -0700
Processing by Admin::ProgramsController#add_card as JS
  Parameters: {"card_class"=>"Startup", "program"=>"9", "id"=>"18"}
Completed 404 Not Found in 151ms
```

and got this error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Program with id=18):
  activerecord (3.2.14) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:344:in `find_one'
  activerecord (3.2.14) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:315:in `find_with_ids'
  activerecord (3.2.14) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:107:in `find'
  activerecord (3.2.14) lib/active_record/querying.rb:5:in `find'
  cancan (1.6.10) lib/cancan/model_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:20:in `find'
  cancan (1.6.10) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:116:in `find_resource'
  cancan (1.6.10) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:68:in `load_resource_instance'
  cancan (1.6.10) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:32:in `load_resource'
  cancan (1.6.10) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:25:in `load_and_authorize_resource'
  cancan (1.6.10) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:10:in `block in add_before_filter'
  activesupport (3.2.14) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in `_run__1885131641261797116__process_action__2504614609988729783__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.14) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.14) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.14) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (3.2.14) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.14) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.14) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
  activerecord (3.2.14) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:608:in `call'
  warden (1.1.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.1.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.1.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
  remotipart (1.2.1) lib/remotipart/middleware.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.14) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.14) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.14) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__4589402527262645124__call__3300629511699191158__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.14) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.14) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.14) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.14) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.14) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.14) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
  railties (3.2.14) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.14) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:143:in `pass'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:155:in `invalidate'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:71:in `call!'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
  railties (3.2.14) lib/rails/engine.rb:484:in `call'
  railties (3.2.14) lib/rails/application.rb:231:in `call'
  railties (3.2.14) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  /home/webadmin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/passenger-4.0.10/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:77:in `process_request'
  /home/webadmin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/passenger-4.0.10/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:140:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
  /home/webadmin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/passenger-4.0.10/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:108:in `main_loop'
  /home/webadmin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/passenger-4.0.10/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:441:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
```

it looks like cancan try to find a Program record with id 18 but in my case I don't have any  logic in my controller to use the id param from my call to find a program, I use the program param for this. How can I change this behavior and not change my call? the problem I don't have a program with id=18, the id in this case is the id of the card and id of program is 9

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late to answer this question, but first maybe there's a conceptual error in the way you named the params and routes and in the way you are trying to create a card related to a program which is not the program id you want. You have to fix the routes to be conceptually correct, for example using:

```
/admin/programs/<program_id>/featured_cards   # to list cards of a program   
/admin/programs/<program_id>/featured_cards/new  # to create a new card related to a program
```

Answer (score -1):

I changed the `load_and_authorize_resource` to `authorize_resource` and this solved my problem, seems like in this case cancan does not try to load the record using the id param from call

Comment: if you're calling /programs/18, then Rails conventions are going to assume you're looking for Program ID=18.